# LiveServer of VisualStudioCode doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

I have tried to uninstall vsc with all it's files. .vscode folder, data in roaming. Uninstall and install config of all vsc (especially LiveServer). I have tried to change the value LiveServer > Settings:Https.Enable to true and then false, and viceversa.

I have tried to add C:\Windows\System32 to Path and it doesn't work yet.

I'm using two computers to codding, and both have the same problem.

When I use ctrl + L, ctrl + O or using "Open with live Server" it doesn't open de browser, but appears "Server is Started ad port: 5500. If go to "localhost:5500" I can see de file that opened and it can refresh by itself.

Please, help me.

I've tried:

- Uninstall VSC (completely I think. .vscode on %userprofile%, and %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming > Code
- Uninstall (before installing) LiveServer
- Add custom browser to it's settings
- Put false/true to LiveServer > Settings:Https.Enable
- Reset default LiveServer settings
- Add C:\Windows\System32 to Path

Comment: what version of the extension do you have installed? what browsers do you have on your machine? which one is set as the default browser? what happens if you choose a different default browser?

Comment: Live Server v5.7.9.
I have only Microsoft Edge. You made remember I've tried to install chrome and make it default system browser, but it doesn't work also.